# Reviving my Bricked Tablet via adb and Samsung's Download Mode

Tags: adb, unbricking

Okay, here's the story:

I have a **Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4"**. The OS doesn't matter, because it's gone. I had lollipop 5.0.2, decided to root it. OK, rooted it fine. Then decided to get CyanogenMod on it. Welp, when I was wiping it, I accidentally deleted the CM install zip with the rest. I was using TWRP to install the thing, but then I couldn't access it. So, I got Odin and tried to install that and the Clockwork mod. No help, and now Odin throws the "nand write start" error, which, from what I can tell from Google, mean my partitions are screwed up. (**Edit**: I re-flashed TWRP, and there was no error, but there is this error when getting ClockworkMod. Probably a messed up tar.)

**Long story short**, all I can do is use the Samsung Download mode, I have Odin, and I may have messed up my partitions.

I **do** have an adb backup, which means if I can get adb to recognize me device, I can roll it back.

adb seems like the best way to go, which is why I titled the post as it is.

Comment: Is your device connecting in fast boot mode? Use that to flash cwm or twrp. You won't need odin for that.

Comment: @Hunter I don't think so -- Samsung uses "Download Mode", which I beleive is a replacement.

Comment: @Hunter I can flash TWRP successfully, but I'm not able to boot to it. If I were able to get to it, I think my troubles would be over :]

Comment: @Hunter I may not be booting normally -- I can't start up with just the power button. I seem to have to use power + vol down + home, which is the key combo for download mode if I were to hold it down through boot.

Comment: The download mode you are reffering is something that Samsung has for it's own devices. Fastboot helps in forcing your uploads on the device. Check these steps which are for samsung galxy s: Volume up and home until the black and white Galaxy S boot Screen came up and then right away volume up+home+powerbutton at the same time.

Comment: From the boot screen that has been displayed for the entire night last night, vol Up + Home doesn't work. I'm currently trying to boot into download, then cancel to restart the tablet, where I will try your keys...... No cigar. I pressed your keys in the order you listed 'em, and held 'em down for about 10 seconds. No screen change -- does fastboot have a screen?

Comment: Well sorry but i think it's not implemented in samsung like it. Can you confirm that you can connect via odin in download mode. I want this to see if it connects or not?

Comment: Yes, I have flashed TWRP multiple times. I can connect OK

Comment: I also just checked -- Odin does recognize.

Comment: If you can connect to odin, then download adb drivers from.http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1895220&d=1366378237 and tell me if adb is working or not. For that first start your tab, and then connect your tab with pc and then open command panel in the folder where adb is, and typing "adb devices" in it.

Comment: ADB does not work, as you can tell from my post. Nor `adb devices` or `fastboot devices` recognizes the tablet. When I was in TWRP, it was able to recognize is via adb unload. --Tested on Ubuntu with adb installed via apt-get

Comment: Oh sorry, then just try one of the root toolkits for samsung. Google it up and see. I wasn't able to find any for tab but see if other toolkits work for you or not.

Comment: What is a root toolkit? If it gives root, I have one right here I used to get root before I bricked

Comment: Sorry to comment late first check my answer kk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what you need to do:

1) First follow this guide to erase evrything on your tab  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2610757   for this you would need latest odin, find it online or use the version given in thread. You also need a pit file and stock rom for your device.
   a) Pit file: Use the SM-T700 pit file from here  http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/general/extracted-sm-t800-pit-download-t3071209/post59859123#post59859123
   b) Stock rom: Use the stock rom according to your android version and country region. Download from here  http://www.mrcrab.net/stockrom/sm-t700.html

2) Then flash a new recovery, apparently twrp as it seems to work correctly on your device.

3) Then root your tab using this guide  http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/development/root-cf-autoroot-t700-t2805366

Post your results after this or following this guide.
And also use the first guide I linked for removing all partitions and not the other one. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Since I want to upgrade to Cyanogenmod anyway, can I use CM instead of the Stock ROM?

Comment: No first you have to install the stock rom itself, remember it's bricked so you have to install the stock one only. And yeah the room is fine.

Comment: OK, getting the stock ROM from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/47569/T700XXU1BOE3_T700XAR1BOE1_XAR/) instead, since it'll be direct from Samsung.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter until you download the correct rom, and hey download the Odin from there too.

Comment: OK, so once this is finished I should *then* be able to switch over to CM? As in, I'll have factory reset, and I can re-do my process, not screwing up this time around?

Comment: Not, just first do these steps and then post your results as success and failures. First get the stock rom on this. Ok

Comment: Right. I'm saying once I get stock ROM, and I check everything to be OK, I'll be good-to-go, right?

Comment: Right now are you following the guide or will do it later cause these things I mentioned should be complete by now. And yes you will be good to go, first get the stock rom and then ask another question for getting CM on tab and we'll answer it later.

Comment: Alright, that sounds like a good idea. I'll follow your idea, report back, backup with adb, and ask a new question.

Comment: Dude, I love you. Thank you so much, I thought I was a goner. Unfortunately, the bloatware is back, but I have my tablet working again!! :D

Comment: Good grief now you can post a question for getting CM on your tab I'll answer it there. Kk

Comment: no, it's fine, I got CM & GApps on here fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the wifi-variant of the tablet.

Download the stock firmware from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T700/). This file can be flashed via Odin when you're in Download-Mode. From there on you can restart your process of flashing TWRP and then the new ROM.

Comment: I'm not finding anything here for the US. I've tried searching, "US", "U.S.", "United Sta", and "America"

Comment: According to [here](http://www.sammobile.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26289) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2650889), US versions are listed as "Celluar South", but clicking that in the site you linked leads me to a "File not Found"

Comment: I found two other sources. If I flash these, since they have no guarantee of being official, is there a risk of breaking the tablet more?

Comment: Choosing the Cellular South version sounds good. I would try to use the one from sammobile as I'm not sure if other sources are trustworthy even though sammobiles download speeds are ridiculously slow and you have to register for the site. This link works for me: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/47569/T700XXU1BOE3_T700XAR1BOE1_XAR/

Comment: "File not found" For Chrome, Chrome Incognito, or TOR.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe try it with yet another browser? Yesterday I managed to start the download of the file. Maybe something with your proxy-settings? I'm sorry but I can't help you any further. If you manage to download the firmware your problem will be fixed. Of course you could still try out the other sources as you will be flashing another ROM over the stock firmware anyways.